# Тестовая версия 1с на сервере для теста бекенда на PHP

Tags: php, 1с

У меня стоит задача, разработать бэкенд, который будет служить прослойкой между 1с и мобильным приложением. Доступа к приложению 1с у меня нет, но надо как-то тестить запросы. Есть ли где-то на сервере в открытом доступе тестовая база 1с, к которой можно делать запросы?

Необходимо разработать функцилонал на PHP, который получает данные с 1С

Comment: А без прослойки не обойтись? Какова общая суть задачи? В открытом доступе, предполагаю, вряд ли найдете тестовый контур (базу 1С). Опять же, 1С поддерживает Web- и http- сервисы. От этого будет зависеть взаимодействие.

Comment: Вы должны узнать как подключаться к 1С для начала, через SOAP, скорее всего, и работать придется с XML вероятно. Затем просто можете имитировать запросы от нее, используя Insomnia или Postman, отправляя данные на свой сервер.